# Laravel / Blade: @yield or @extends Layout

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

When visiting my page **localhost.com**, the Visitor is directed to the welcome.blade.php

Now my question of the best approach for using a Layout:

1. **@yield** content in 'welcome'? (eg. by using this as Main-Template and implementing dynamic Content)

OR

2. **@extends('Layout')** **@section('Content')**
   (eg. by including Layout Templates in every Content)?

Comment: Please elaborate what do you want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use both of them. Why? because in order to apply changes and to follow laravel conventions you'll be creating a `layout.blade.php` or `app.blade.php` in which you'll be using `@yield` which will be used to `insert all the changes from the pages in the layout.

Whereas the `@extend` will help you define the pages layout. What `extend` does is it inserts the required information in the page i.e. ** insert the layout or app.blade.php ** in the page and then insert the required data as you define your `@yield()` in your pages.

Consider the following code to understand it better:

**Defining A Blade Layout (app.blade.php or layout.blade.php)**

```
<!-- Stored in resources/views/layouts/master.blade.php -->

<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Using A Blade Layout ( or index.blade.php )**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('sidebar')    
    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@stop

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@stop
```

You can read more about the `@yield()` and `@extend()` in laravel's documentaiton over here:

assuming you're using Laravel 8.x.x

Answer (score 0):

**@yield()** is used to insert changes from all our pages into the main template of our project.

**@extends()** is used to include the main layouts of our project on every page.

For more information please visit the following link:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates

By the way, your question is not clear.